# No Activity found to handle Intent, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

I am developing a project on Android that deals with images either from the camera or from the sd-card. I had this working fine until earlier I was fiddling with the code and broke it. It was too late to undo and I can't seem to find the solution.

After the image is selected and processed, a list should be returned but now I get an Activity not Found exception, [here](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/349/screenshotat20120310035.png) is a picture.

If anybody has any idea whats going on I'd appreciate it!

**EDIT**

Just got it, was a silly mistake, I had

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Results)
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class)
```

Comment: Answer your own question with an answer instead of just editting the post, and mark that new answer as the accepted answer. That way, this post will be "closed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, I had

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Results)
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "" to the calling Activity.